# Prove that the subspaces $T := \{\frac{1}{n}: n ∈ \mathbb{N}\}$ and $S := T \cup \{0\}$ of $\mathbb{E}^1$ are not homeomorphic

Tags: general-topology

Prove that  the subspaces $T := \{\frac{1}{n}: n ∈ \mathbb{N}\}$ and $S := T \cup \{0\}$ of $\mathbb{E}^1$ are not homeomorphic, if it's necessary, use that $\forall \varepsilon >0\ \exists n_\varepsilon\in\mathbb{N} \ \forall n\in\mathbb{N} \ (n>n_\varepsilon \Rightarrow d_2(0,\frac{1}{n}) = |\frac{1}{n}-0| < \varepsilon)$.

I tried to prove by creating a function that it was not continuous, but I didn't well.

Comment: Creating a function that is not continuous can't help you prove that those two spaces are not homeomorphic.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I take it that $\mathbb E^1$ is the real line? Then the open neighborhoods of $0\in S$ all contain more than one element. But in $T$, the sets with a single element are all open. So a bijective function $\varphi:S\to T$ can't be continuous at $0$, since $\varphi^{-1}(\varphi(\{0\}))=\{0\}$, which is not open, even though $\varphi(\{0\})$ is open.

Comment: My really thank you very much.

Answer (score 4):

$T$ is not compact, but $S$ is.